# MPAndroidChart Realtime LineChart jumps on addEntry

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to display values coming in periodically (every 3 seconds). The values are added to the dataset on the main thread, then `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10)` is called, and afterwards, the view is moved to the end, using `moveViewToX(dataSet.getEntryCount())`.

This, however, results in the chart moving ever so slightly to the left (about a 10th of the width between two datapoints), instead of showing the newest data. If I scroll between adding two points, the view jumps to the beginning of the dataset.

How can I achieve the behavior found in the example app, with the view showing 10 entries at once and scrolling to the newest entry on adding?

This is how I initialize the chart:

```
// Initializing
v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.device_detail_element_graph, parent, false);
LineChart chart = (LineChart) v.findViewById(R.id.lineChart);

LineData lineData = new LineData();
lineData.setDrawValues(false);
chart.setDrawBorders(false);
chart.setDrawMarkers(false);
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
chart.setDescription(null);
chart.setData(lineData);
chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
chart.setData(lineData);
chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And how I add new datapoints (called periodically):

```
LineData data = chart.getData();

ILineDataSet dataSet = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

if(dataSet == null){
    dataSet = new LineDataSet(null, "Dynamic data");
    dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    dataSet.setHighlightEnabled(false);
    data.addDataSet(dataSet);
}
int  lastIndex = dataSet.getEntryCount();

dataSet.addEntry(new Entry(lastIndex, (float) newValue.getValue()));

data.notifyDataChanged();
chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20.0f);

chart.moveViewToX(dataSet.getEntryCount());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. When I called the function that added new entrys to the graph, I always called `notifyDataChanged` on the `RecyclerView` the graph was ultimately in. This somehow reset the view window of the graph, resulting in the jumps.